# Jetson Xavier NX unreadable pyserial (usb)

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, pyserial, nvidia-jetson

I have 2 devices connected to Weighting terminal CAS-CI200A via RS-232:

- Lenovo notebook with Kubuntu 20.04 (x86_64 architecture)
- Jetson Xavier NX with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, JetPack 4.5 (aarch64 architecture)

```
    import serial
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
        stopbits=1,
        bytesize=8
    )
    line = ser.readline()
    print(line)
```

Result of the same pyserial library for both devices is:

- for Lenovo: `b'ERR 13\r\n'`
- for Jetson: `b'\x05\x1f\x12\x1f\x12\x1f\x1e\x1e\x0c\x06\r\n'`

Also I try to use: `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` results are the same.

Task is to get `b'ERR 13\r\n'` from Jetson.

I try to `.decode()` the line `b'\x05\x1f\x12\x1f\x12\x1f\x1e\x1e\x0c\x06\r\n'`, but still no success:

[image]

The only difference between the devises is architecture and OS version, the library and the code are the same.

Does anyone know the way to get correct response?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in converter’s driver(parity not work)
1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter

The solution is to [update driver.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=230835)